# Двунаправленный список

Tags: c++, список

Собственно есть у меня список, задаю его таким образом

```
 struct Node       //Структура являющаяся звеном списка
{
  int x;     //Значение x будет передаваться в список

 Node *Next,*Prev; //Указатели на адреса следующего и предыдущего элементов списка
 };

 class List   //Создаем тип данных Список
 {
   Node *Head,*Tail; //Указатели на адреса начала списка и его конца
public:
 List():Head(NULL),Tail(NULL){}; //Инициализируем адреса как пустые
 ~List(); //Деструктор
 void Show(); //Функция отображения списка на экране
 void Add(int x); //Функция добавления элементов в список
};
```

Проблема в том, чтобы в функции добавления элемента(add) добавлялась не 1 переменная, а 6
вот как мне поменять код чтобы всё это сделать? то есть если по задаче то это фамилия автора - название книги – год издания – цена - количество экземпляров – общая стоимость

Добавляю элемент так:

```
 void List::Add(int x)
  {
  Node *temp=new Node; //Выделение памяти под новый элемент структуры
 temp->Next=NULL;  //Указываем, что изначально по следующему адресу пусто
 temp->x=x;//Записываем значение в структуру

 if (Head!=NULL) //Если список не пуст
 {
   temp->Prev=Tail; //Указываем адрес на предыдущий элемент в соотв. поле
   Tail->Next=temp; //Указываем адрес следующего за хвостом элемента
   Tail=temp; //Меняем адрес хвоста
 }
 else //Если список пустой
 {
    temp->Prev=NULL; //Предыдущий элемент указывает в пустоту
    Head=Tail=temp; //Голова=Хвост=тот элемент, что сейчас добавили
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а в чём конкретно беда то?

надо только переделать

1. структуру Node (добавив поля "*фамилия автора - название книги – год издания – цена - количество экземпляров – общая стоимость*")
2. функцию Add (передавая ей эти же параметры...)

Comment: ну добавить то я добавлю, это я понимаю. проблема в этой строке: temp->x=x;//Записываем значение в структуру так и оставлять х? или менять на что-то?

Comment: а что тут такого?

эта стрелочка означает "взять у temp параметр x" и ему уже присваивается новое значение...


если он вам нужен то оставьте.

p.s. но лучше прочтите книгу по С++, в голове сразу прояснится многое...

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Node       //Структура являющаяся звеном списка
{
// тут нужно дописать поля:
  string Family_autor;     //поле фамилия автора 
  string Name_book;        //поле название книги 
  int Year;                //поле год издания 
  int Price;               //поле цена 
  int Count;               //поле количество экземпляров 
  int Total_cost;          //поле общая стоимость

 Node *Next,*Prev; //Указатели на адреса следующего и предыдущего элементов списка
 };

 class List   //Создаем тип данных Список
 {
   Node *Head,*Tail; //Указатели на адреса начала списка и его конца
public:
 List():Head(NULL),Tail(NULL){}; //Инициализируем адреса как пустые
 ~List(); //Деструктор
 void Show(); //Функция отображения списка на экране
 void Add(int x); //Функция добавления элементов в список
};


void List::Add(string family_autor, string name_book, int year, int price, 
int count, int total_cost)//передаем параметры
  {
  Node *temp=new Node; //Выделение памяти под новый элемент структуры
 temp->Next=NULL;  //Указываем, что изначально по следующему адресу пусто
//Записываем значение в структуру
 temp->Family_autor=family_autor;
 temp->Name_book=name_book;
 temp->Year=year;
 temp->Price=price;
 temp->Count=count;
 temp->total_cost=total_cost;
 if (Head!=NULL) //Если список не пуст
 {
   temp->Prev=Tail; //Указываем адрес на предыдущий элемент в соотв. поле
   Tail->Next=temp; //Указываем адрес следующего за хвостом элемента
   Tail=temp; //Меняем адрес хвоста
 }
 else //Если список пустой
 {
    temp->Prev=NULL; //Предыдущий элемент указывает в пустоту
    Head=Tail=temp; //Голова=Хвост=тот элемент, что сейчас добавили
 }
}
```